# What is the difference between array_agg ()and json_agg () in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

What are the major differences between `array_agg()` and `json_agg()` and what are the basic scenarios where these functions are used?

Comment: Did you mean to tag `sql-server`? array_agg() and json_agg() are not related to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: `array_agg` returns an `ARRAY`, and `json_agg` returns a `JSON` in the form of a JSON array, there is also the similar `jsonb_agg` which does the same thing for `jsonb`, as well as `json_object_agg` which does key/value pairs. What is unclear about [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html)?

Comment: In addition to Erwin's good answer: SQL is a typed language; every column and expression has a data type. The result types of the functions in your question are different. So you use them depending on what data type you need.

Answer (score 1):

[`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) aggregates a Postgres array (actual array type that corresponds to the element types it's built from).

[`json_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) aggregates a JSON array (type `json`).

There are also the related [`jsonb_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) or [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE). You can guess what those do.